# Binary Tree Questions

Tags: heap, binary-search-tree, priority-queue

Currently studying for an exam, and whilst reading through some notes, I had a few questions.

1. I know that the height of a Binary Search Tree is Log(n). Does this mean the depth is also Log(n)?
2. What is maximum depth of a node in a full binary tree with n nodes? This related to the first question; if the height of a Binary Tree is Log(n), would the maximum depth also be Log(n)?
3. I know that the time complexity of searching for a node in a binary search tree is O(Log(n)), which I understand. However, I read that the worst case time complexity is O(N). In what scenario would it take O(N) time to find an element?
4. THIS IS A PRIORITY QUEUE/ HEAP QUESTION. In my lecture notes, it says the following statement:

   > If we use an array for Priority Queues, en-queuing takes O(1) and de-queuing takes O(n). In a sorted Array, en-queue takes O(N) and de-queue takes O(1).

   I'm having a hard time understanding this. Can anyone explain?

Sorry for all the questions, really need some clarity on a few of these topics.

Comment: A balanced binary search tree has height of the order log(N) (same as depth, if you draw the tree from the root down the page). However nothing you've said indicates that the tree is balanced. An unbalanced tree is a list of height O(N), not O(logN). The same goes for the time complexity.

When you say "a full binary tree" to me that means that you have exactly (2^M)-1 nodes in a balanced tree of height M. Is that what you mean? Most of the time, a tree will have some other number of nodes, so it cannot be "full".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caveat:  I'm a little rusty, but here goes ...

Height and depth of a binary tree are synonymous--more or less.  height is the maximum depth along any path from root to leaf.  But, when you traverse a tree, you have a concept of current depth.  root node has depth 0, its children have depth 1, its grandchildren depth 2.  If we stop here, the height of the tree is 3, but the maximum depth [we visited] is 2.  Otherwise, they are often interchanged when talking about the tree overall.

Before we get to some more of your questions, it's important to note that binary trees come in various flavors.  Balanced or unbalanced.  With a perfectly balanced tree, all nodes except those at maximum height will have their left/right links non-null.  For example, with n nodes in the tree, let n = 1024.  Perfectly balanced the height is log2(n) which is 10 (e.g. 1024 == 2^10).

When you search a perfectly balanced tree, the search *is* O(log2(n)) because starting from the root node, you choose to follow either left or right, and each time you do, you eliminate 1/2 of the nodes.  In such a tree with 1024 elements, the depth is 10 and you make 10 such left/right decisions.

Most tree algorithms, when you add a new node, will rebalance the tree on the fly (e.g. AVL or RB (red black)) trees.  So, you get a perfectly balanced tree, all the time, more or less.

But ...

Let's consider a really bad algorithm.  When you add a new node, it just appends it to the left link on the child with the greatest depth [or the new node becomes the new root].  The idea is fast append, and "we'll rebalance later".

If we search this "bad" tree, if we've added n nodes, the tree looks like a doubly linked list using the parent link and the left link [remember all right links are NULL].  This is linear time search or O(n).

We did this deliberately, but it can still happen with some tree algorithm and/or combinations of data.  That is, the data is such that it gets naturally placed on the left link because that's where it's correct to place it based on the algorithm's placement function.

Priority queues are like regular queues except each piece of data has a priority number associated with it.

In an ordinary queue, you just push/append onto the end.  When you dequeue, you shift/pop from the front.  You *never* need to insert anything in the middle.  Thus, enqueue and dequeue are both O(1) operations.

The O(n) comes from the fact that if you have to do an insertion into the middle of an array, you have to "part the waters" to make space for the element you want to insert.  For example, if you need to insert after the first element [which is array[0]], you will be placing the new element at array[1], but first you have to move array[1] to array[2], array[2] to array[3], ...  For an array of n, this is O(n) effort.

When removing an element from an array, it is similar, but in reverse.  If you want to remove array[1], you grab it, then you must "close the gap" left by your removal by array[1] = array[2], array[2] = array[3], ...  Once again, an O(n) operation.

In a sorted array, you just pop off the end.  It's the one you want already.  Hence O(1).  To add an element, its an insertion into the correct place.  If your array is 1,2,3,7,9,12,17 and you want to add 6, that's new value for array[4], and you have to move 7,9,12,17 out of the way as above.

Priority queue just appends to the array, hence O(1).  But to find the correct element to dequeue, you scan the array array[0], array[1], ... remembering the first element position for a given priority, if you find a better priority, you remember that.  When you hit the end, you know which element you need, say it's j.  Now you have to remove j from array, and that an O(n) operation as above.

It's slightly more complex than all that, but not by two much.